# Wrapping image properly in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview, image-size

I would like to create a layout that looks like this:

```
-----------------
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|   ImageView   |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------
|Button |Button |
```

The size of the image itself can be different, but I would like the entire screen to be filled with the imageview and the two buttons below it regardless of the size of the image, on all devices.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a RelativeLayout:

Put the two Buttons in a LinearLayout.

Each of the Buttons wiil have a `android:layout_weight="1"` and a `android:layout_width="0dp"`

The LinearLayout has to be aligned to the Parent's bottom: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Then add the ImageView with the attributes: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`, `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Note that `match_parent` fills the **remaining space**.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: This layout is light and avoids nested weights.

**[EDIT]**

This is an alternative design, that seems to best match your **newly expressed** needs

To set the image in the **center** and the buttons just **below** it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but what can I do if I don't want the buttons to be on bottom of the parent, and the imageview not on top of the parent, but both aligned vertically?

Comment: `I would like the entire screen to be filled with the imageview and the two buttons below it` - This is what my layout does.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the aspect of the image I put in the imageView isn't suitable to fill a large enough part of the screen to look nice, in that case I would like the imageview and the buttons below it to be  aligned vertically.

Comment: If you set the image by using the `src` attribute (and not `background`), you can use the ImageView attribute `scaletype="centerInside"`. For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Anyway I added to my answer an **alternative design** to `center the image in its container and attach the buttons below it`.

Comment: Thank you, however the answer of Moradiya Akash was what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use ,

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

attribute for ImageView.

For Buttons use,

```
android:layout_weight="1" for both.
```

Comment: Unfortunately scaleType="fitXY" will not keep the aspect ratio, and if my image is too large, the entire layout will be larger than the screen.

Comment: ya then give ImageView width and height static and then use adjustViewBounds=true, so it will maintain your aspect ratio. and your imageview should fill your layout

Comment: I can't give the ImageView static dimensions, because I need the layout to be displayed correctly on different devices with different screen sizes and densities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will keep the `Button` at the bottom of the screen and give the remaining space to the `ImageView`